# How do I set the Settings property in XmlTextWriter, so that I can write each XML attribute on its own line?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlwriter, xmltextwriter

I have this bit of code, which serializes an object to a file.  I'm trying to get each XML attribute to output on a separate line.  The code looks like this:

```
public static void ToXMLFile(Object obj, string filePath)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.Settings = settings; // Fails here.  Property is read only.

    using (Stream baseStream = writer.BaseStream)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
    }
}
```

The only problem is, the `Settings` property of the `XmlTextWriter` object is read-only.

How do I set the `Settings` property on the `XmlTextWriter` object, so that the `NewLineOnAttributes` setting will work?

---

Well, I thought I needed an `XmlTextWriter`, since `XmlWriter` is an `abstract` class.  Kinda confusing if you ask me.  *Final working code is here:*

```
/// <summary>
/// Serializes an object to an XML file; writes each XML attribute to a new line.
/// </summary>
public static void ToXMLFile(Object obj, string filePath)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the static `Create()` method of `XmlWriter`.

```
XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings);
```

Note that you can set the `NewLineOnAttributes` property in the settings.

Comment: It didn't instantiate.  It says it executed, but the object so created is null.  Note: I used `XmlTextWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings) as XmlTextWriter;`

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That means that `XmlWriter.Create(...)` doesn't create a `XmlTextWriter`. When you look at the output, you'll find that it returns a `XmlWellFormedWriter`. It would be wise though to treat it like an `XmlWriter`.

Comment: So how do I get it to an `XmlTextWriter`?

Comment: Never mind, got it working, thanks.  You were right, I just needed an `XmlWriter`.  The `XmlWriter` class is an `abstract` class, but you can create instances of it anyway.  And the instances so created are called something else.  That's just bizarre.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is old, anyway it's actually possible to set indentation for the `XMLTextWriter`. Unlike with the `XMLwriter`, you don't have to pass through the settings; you should use the `Formatting` property:

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, Encoding.UTF8);
w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

See
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting(v=vs.110).aspx