# c# how to write in xml serialization instead of json

Tags: c#, json, xml-serialization

I know json very well but not sure how to do with xml serialization. i would be glad if you dont mind to change json codes for xml serialization. thanks so much!

how to replace this with xml serializer Setting

```
       //Serializer Settings
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All};
```

how to replace this with xml serialize object in a correct way

```
        //Serialized String
        var serilizedObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

how to replace this with xml deserialize object in a correct way

```
 var fromDb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObject>(strFromDb, settings);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set the Settings property in XmlTextWriter, so that I can write each XML attribute on its own line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237165/how-do-i-set-the-settings-property-in-xmltextwriter-so-that-i-can-write-each-xm)

Comment: The duplicate is slightly more specialized but, the question and answer illustrate exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlSerializer, check out this page, it contains examples.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx