# XDocument.CreateWriter using XmlWriterSettings

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I'm trying to create an XMLWriter for an XDocument, and also apply settings to it, but I can't figure out how.

Here's what I have so far.

```
        var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings()
        {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };
        var request = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = request.CreateWriter())
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("CUSTOMER");
            writer.WriteElementString("ADDRESS", "123 Fake St.");
            writer.WriteElementString("CITY", "San Jose");
            writer.WriteElementString("STATE", "CA");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
```

I can't figure out how to apply writerSettings to the writer.  The XDocument.CreateWriter() method doesn't take any parameters to specify the XMLWriterSettings.  And, after it's created, the Settings property doesn't have a setter.

If there's no way to use CreateWriter() and apply settings, how else could I accomplish something equivalent, and end up with the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`XDocument.Save(XmlWriter)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can create your own `XmlWriter` supplying the `XmlWriterSettings` parameters, and write the contents of the `XDocument` to it.

Alternatively, you can just call one of the [`XDocument.ToString` overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which omit the XML declaration from the returned string (if that was all you wanted to configure).

Your example updated below to show both options:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = new XDocument();

        using (var writer = request.CreateWriter())
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("CUSTOMER");
            writer.WriteElementString("ADDRESS", "123 Fake St.");
            writer.WriteElementString("CITY", "San Jose");
            writer.WriteElementString("STATE", "CA");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }

        // XDocument.ToString() will print:
        //<CUSTOMER>
        //  <ADDRESS>123 Fake St.</ADDRESS>
        //  <CITY>San Jose</CITY>
        //  <STATE>CA</STATE>
        //</CUSTOMER>
        Console.WriteLine(request.ToString());

        // And here's how to use the XmlWriterSettings with XDocument.Save:
        var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings()
        {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml", writerSettings))
        {
            request.Save(writer);
        }

        // The above will write (you could adjust the XmlWriterSettings to add whitespace):
        //<CUSTOMER><ADDRESS>123 Fake St.</ADDRESS><CITY>San Jose</CITY><STATE>CA</STATE></CUSTOMER>
    }
}
```

Or if you're not using any other functionality of `XDocument`, you could just create your own `XmlWriter` instance in the first place, and add the nodes to that, and leave out the `XDocument` interaction altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the static method of xmlwriter, which is create()

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePath, settings))
{ 
//do your thing 
}
```

I've ran into this problem before and I do agree it's not very obvious, especially when trying to do a new xmlwriter.

Edit: also possible duplicate of [How do I set the Settings property in XmlTextWriter, so that I can write each XML attribute on its own line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237165/how-do-i-set-the-settings-property-in-xmltextwriter-so-that-i-can-write-each-xm)

Which you can refer to for further reading if you'd like!